# XSLT- using global variable in template

Tags: xslt, global-variables, param

I am sure there must be something obvious I am doing wrong. (Altova XMLSpy 2012 professional sp1)

I have declared and want to use a global variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="myDTD.dtd" />

    <!-- Edit these parameters if necessary. -->
    <xsl:param name="outObject" select="POSIT"/>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:element name="section">
                <!-- debug -->
            <xsl:element name="para">Debug: outObject = <xsl:value-of select="$outObject"/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE section SYSTEM "myDTD.dtd">
<section>
    <title/>
    <para>Debug: outObject = </para>
</section>
```

I would have thought that I could access the value of $outObject here. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter is unpopulated. You are defining it outside of any template, and therefore out of any existing context. Without further context, the path `POSIT` selects nothing. You should use something like:

```
<xsl:param name="outObject" select="/root/path/to/POSIT"/>
```

This is assuming `POSIT` is an element in your XML input, whose value you want to get - not the *string* `"POSIT"` which needs to be quoted:

```
<xsl:param name="outObject" select="`POSIT`"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I just wanted a string. Thanks. Nice explanation of the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you made the same mistake as I *always* do.

If you want to use the string "POSIT", you have to use single quotes:

```
<xsl:param name="outObject" select="'POSIT'"/>
```